# Swift 3 playground logs dates in local format. How?

Tags: nsdateformatter, swift3, swift-playground

If you run a line like this in a Playground in the US:

```
let today = Date()
```

You'll see output like this to the right of the source code:

```
"Sep 26, 2016, 8:17 PM"
```

That appears to be the date, displayed in the local time zone, using medium date and time style.

How does that work?

If you try to print the date:

```
print("today = \(today)"
```

You'll see "Today = 2016-09-27 00:18:55 +0000\n", which is UTC, and appears to be unix date format.

What function is the Playground using to display the date when you first create a date? Is there a way to get to that output format from code or from the debug console?

Up until now I've created a date formatter that I use to log dates, display them in the console, etc.

Comment: You can subclass and override the conformance to [CustomPlaygroundQuicklookable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customplaygroundquicklookable)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I want to be able to use `print(aDate)` in code, or `e aDate` in the debugger console, and get a date in medium format in my current time zone and locale.

Comment: I've created an extension to Date that lets me say print(aDate.localDateString), but obviously the ability to display a date in the user's locale in medium format is lurking somewhere. Maybe it's just in the Playground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's lurking in [`CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customplaygroundquicklookable) protocol, which `Date` conforms to:

```
if case .text(let str) = today.customPlaygroundQuickLook {
    print(str)
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I wish the normal description method for dates would log in the local time zone and locale, with an option to display in UTC.

Comment: Most of the problems with Date I see on SO are related to the timezone. I wish Apple make that change too

Comment: Its very common to want to be able to log a date in your local time zone. More common then wanting to see it in UTC, I'd wager. It's unfortunate that logging a date in an easy-to-read format requires a hidden playground protocol.

Comment: That. And subscripting String requires Index instead of Int. The Swift team so be so stubborn sometimes

Comment: Subscripting Strings I understand. Unicode strings are strange beasts, requiring a variable amount of data to express, and with various ways of representing the same set of glyphs. I wish they'd offer a "longhand" mapping that would force every glyph into a 32 bit int and then allow treating it as a pure array of unicode characters.

Comment: That would make a life a lot easier. In most cases you'd use the current form of String where the internal storage is flexible and there can be various ways of representing a glyph (e.g. character code followed by accent code or unique character-with-accent code) and an array mode that uses more storage but allows straightforward random-access indexing by glyph number.